# Convert a string to char* array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have sentence of char*

```
char *s1 = "coding hero";
```

How do I Convert to

```
char *s1 = {coding hero};
```

Comment: A string is already a character array in C.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't convert a `char *` (string) to a `char*` array but rather to a `char` array:

```
char s1[] = "coding hero";
```

A `char *` (string) is similar to a `char` array for most purposes, but not identical.  There are slightly different rules that apply to the two of them.

If desired, you can also write:

```
char s1[] = { 'c', 'o', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'o', '\0' };
```